# emulator for windows 10 on a system doesn't support virtualisation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am working on a universal application with windows 10,and I want to test my application on an emulator. I tried to install the windows 10 emulator in visual Studio, but I have a problem with the installation that said that my PC doesn't support visualization

my Pc is:
Os:Windows 10 Professional 64 bits,processor x64

Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  P6200 @2.13Ghz

RAM :4Go(3.80 used)

Is there please any emulators that doesn't use visualization?
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that your CPU doesn't supports VT-x which is required to run Hyper-V.

http://ark.intel.com/products/50176/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6200-3M-Cache-2_13-GHz

You could change your CPU or use real devices with remote debug. Depending on your needs, the second choice might be a good one if you need some specific capabilities such as sensors not present on your main machine.